# modules name Webpack & vue-cli when authoring library

Tags: webpack, vue-cli-3

**TL;DR;**

**How to rename `webpackChunkName` with `vue-cli` in `--target lib` mode?**

---

Hi folks, 
I am authoring a library for Vue js with `vue-cli`.

This line produces the output of my lib into *umd*, *umd.min* & *common-js*:

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name mylib ./src/components/mylib.vue --dest ./dist
```

Since my lib has async modules (i18n locales in json files), I want to modify Webpack to control the output of all the files in the final dist folder, but was not successful.

Before I externalize all the locales files for performance, I had this:

```
dist/
|- mylib.common.js
|- mylib.umd.js
|- mylib.umd.min.js
|- mylib.css
```

Now that a locale is imported on demand with:

```js
import(/* webpackInclude: /\.json$/, webpackChunkName: "[request]" */ `./i18n/${locale}`)
    .then(response => (this.texts = response.default))
```

This is the output:

```
dist/
|- mylib.common.js
|- mylib.umd.js
|- mylib.umd.min.js
|- mylib.css
|- en.common.min.js
|- en.umd.js
|- en.umd.min.js
|- es.common.min.js
|- es.umd.js
|- es.umd.min.js
|- de.common.min.js
|- de.umd.js
|- de.umd.min.js
...
```

Ideally I would like to get only one locale file for all the versions of my lib as the generated locale files are exactly the same for *umd* & *common-js*, and organized in a folder like so:

```
dist/
|- mylib.common.js
|- mylib.umd.js
|- mylib.umd.min.js
|- mylib.css
|- i18n
   |- en.js
   |- es.js
   |- de.js
   ...
```

I tried tweaking the import [`webpack magic comment`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments) but got 3 i18n folders like following:

```js
import(/* webpackInclude: /\.json$/, webpackChunkName: "i18n/[request]" */ `./i18n/${locale}`)
    .then(response => (this.texts = response.default))
```

```
dist/
|- mylib.common.
   |- i18n
   |- en.js
|- mylib.umd.
   |- i18n
   |- en.js
|- mylib.umd.min.
   |- i18n
   |- en.js
```

When I add this to my `vue.config.js`, it modifies the build for my documentation into `docs/` (`vue-cli-service build`), but it does not work for my lib into `dist/` (`vue-cli-service build --target lib`):

```
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      filename: '[name].testing-bundle.js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].testing-bundle.js'
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a suitable workaround!

I ended up adding a postbuild script (triggered automatically after build) as followed:

```
"postbuild-bundle": "rm -rf ./dist/libname.common.i18n ./dist/libname.umd.i18n && mv ./dist/libname.umd.min.i18n ./dist/i18n"
```